# Show that gcd of any two consecutive odd integers is 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the gcd of any two consecutive odd integers

Comment: It's 1 ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Please do research out before asking questions and don't spam math.StackExchange

Answer (score 5):

$\gcd(a,a+2)=\gcd(a,a+2-a)=\gcd(a,2)$. Since $a$ is odd, $2\not\mid a$ so their $\gcd$ is $1$.